# React native Found errors while update expo sdk 42 to 45.Also setup new environment on react native all packages are exist but still giving errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We have issue found during installing a new expo app whenever we update newer version of expo app from play store our development related things not working so we have updated it with expo sdk 45 but it giving error still so we have set a new environment and trying to solve this after set new environment it still giving errors like below

ERROR  Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js", which threw an exception: Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a fix for everyone, but try:

1. yarn global add expo-cli
   (Mine upgraded when I do this)
2. yarn install
   (To rebuild the package)
3. expo --version
   Then use the package version on the package.json
   "expo-cli": "5.4.12",
4. expo start

Give it a go, you might be lucky...